# Heating water- Is it better to heat all of the water at once?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am curious if it is more efficient to warm a half cup of water and then add an equal amount of room temperature water or warm a full cup together...assuming the water never boils.

Comment: you need to say what does mean better , faster or using less energy and to state on the yield curves of the boiling device. Generally, splitting is not better else it is equivalent.

Comment: Which would use less energy.  The heating device would be a microwave oven.

Comment: My experience is that a microwave oven puts more power into hot water than cold water, but I've seen no other reference for this, so it may just be a rumor I'm trying to start.

Comment: Another possible variable: does the amount of heating power deposited by a microwave oven depend on how much material is absorbing that power? For example, let's say it takes 1 minute to heat 500cc of water by 10°C; how long would it take to heat 1000cc of water by 10°C?

Comment: It kind of depends on the temperature you're trying to reach. It's very possible doubling the amount of energy you put into the half makes it reach boiling, which is a rather huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

For both heating operations, the initial and final states are the same, so the change in internal energy $\Delta U$ is the same. If everything is stored in perfectly insulated containers, this means that the total heat which must be added is the same in both cases.